# JDBC Metadata Fetch Decimal Precision

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot

I am doing a metadata fetch from teradata using jdbc and I would like to get all the datatypes. However for DB fields containing DECIMAL(10,4) I am not able to get the precision. I am attaching my code snippet. Suggestions would be welcome!

```
 DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();

    ResultSet tbls = md.getTables(null, schema, name, null);
            if(false == tbls.next()){
                nonExistingRdbmsTables.add(name);
                LOGGER.error("Table with name {} in schema {} does not exists in source database", name, schema);
                continue;
            }

            RdbmsTableMetadata tableMD = new RdbmsTableMetadata();
            List<String> pkList = new ArrayList();
            ResultSet primaryKeys = md.getPrimaryKeys(null, schema, name);
            while(primaryKeys.next()){
                String pk = primaryKeys.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                pkList.add(pk);
            }
            tableMD.setPkList(pkList);
            LOGGER.info("*****Primary key list for table {} is {}", name, pkList);

            tableMD.setSchema(schema);
            tableMD.setName(name);
            tableMD.setTargetName(targetName);
            tableMD.setTargetSchema(targetSchema);
            List<Column> colList = new ArrayList<>();

            ResultSet cols = md.getColumns(null, schema, name, null);
            while (cols.next()) {
                String columnName = cols.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                String columnType = cols.getString("TYPE_NAME");
                String columnLength = cols.getString("COLUMN_SIZE");
}
```

Is there any way I can query the precision details from jdbc metadata?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Also, what does `cols.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS")` provides you?

Comment: What value do you get for `COLUMN_SIZE` and `DECIMAL_DIGITS`?

Comment: DECIMAL_DIGITS works fine! Thanks guys! This is what i get for not know my information schema well!

Comment: Alex I am using Teradata

Comment: You're welcome; it is also always advisable to look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 4):

For future referencers:-

```
int precision = cols.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
```

This worked fine! Thanks to alex and Mark.

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSetMetaData` provides `getScale(int col)` and `getPrecision(int col)` methods. If those don't give you what you want, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: This would require to have an open `ResultSet` on a table with the column of interest

Comment: I would not prefer to open a result set. For other reasons I have decided to go with DataBase Metadata. Is there any other way to re-engineer this?